# F# syntax with sets and updating

Tags: algorithm, list, f#, set

In F# im trying to remove an occurence in the set if a condition is met, however it's not really working they way i'd like it to.

Comment: where is your attempted solution?

Comment: Could you clarify what's not working, and what code you've tried?  Your code example doesn't appear to match the question you're asking, nor the output you provided at the moment. As to removing an element from a set, you can use `Set.remove item set`, or to filter for elements that match a certain test, you can use `Set.filter booleanTest set`.

Comment: Your latest edit appears to be a completely unrelated question, with code involving "notes", "gears" and "tumblers". Did you paste in the wrong section of code by accident? I'm rolling your edit back to the previous revision; if you also have a question about that code with notes, gears and tumblers, please ask it as a separate question so that each question can be about a single subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick to removing elements from a set is the function `Set.filter`, which takes a function as an argument - `filter` will feed in every value of the set to your function, and add it to a new set if the function returns `true`.  An example implementation might be:

```
let filter f (original : Set<'T>) =
    set [ for value in original do if f value then yield value ]
```

which has type `filter : ('T -> bool) -> Set<'T> -> Set<'T>`.  An example of using it would be

```
filter (fun x -> x % 2 = 0) (set [ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5 ])
```

This filters the set for even numbers, so the return value would be `set [ 2; 4 ]`.

---

I'm not entirely sure what problem you're having exactly, but here is a solution to the game Mastermind using Knuth's algorithm, albeit with a random starting guess, rather than his choice of "1122".

I thought it was quite a nice exercise, though writing the `checkGuess` function was the hardest part of it for me!

You can run a test by opening this in F# interactive by running the function `playMastermind ()`, which will show you its guesses.

```
/// The colours that pegs are allowed to be.
type Peg = Blue | Red | Green | Yellow | Purple | Brown

/// A shared instance of the System.Random () class for all the random number
/// generators.
let private rnd = new System.Random ()

/// Make a random set of four peg colours.
let randomGuess () =
    let randomPeg () =
        match rnd.Next(1, 6) with
        | 1 -> Blue
        | 2 -> Red
        | 3 -> Green
        | 4 -> Yellow
        | 5 -> Purple
        | 6 -> Brown
        | _ -> failwith "Random number generation failed."
    [ randomPeg (); randomPeg (); randomPeg (); randomPeg () ]

/// Iterate over the colours to make all of the possible combinations.
let allPossibles =
    let colours = [ Blue; Red; Green; Yellow; Purple; Brown]
    set [ for a in colours do for b in colours do for c in colours do for d in colours -> [ a; b; c; d ] ] 

/// Get the number of white and black pegs when comparing solution to guess.
let checkGuess solution guess =
    /// Create a map of (colour -> count).
    let toMap = List.countBy id >> Map.ofList
    /// Compute how many pegs' colours are shared in the guesses.
    let mapIntersect map1 map2 =
        let overlap peg count =
            match Map.tryFind peg map2 with
            | None -> 0
            | Some num -> min num count
        Map.fold (fun acc peg count -> acc + overlap peg count) 0 map1
    /// Simply compare to see if each peg is in the correct place.
    let blacks = List.map2 (fun x y -> if x = y then 1 else 0) solution guess |> List.sum
    // The number of pegs of the right colour but the wrong location is the
    // same as the total number of pegs of the right colour subtract the ones
    // that are also in the right place.
    let whites = mapIntersect (toMap solution) (toMap guess) - blacks
    whites, blacks

/// Get a random element of a set.
let randomSetElement set =
    let arr = Set.toArray set
    arr.[rnd.Next (Array.length arr)]

let playMastermind () =
    // This creates a closure so we can check our guess against the solution,
    // without storing the actual value of the solution.
    let checkAnswer = checkGuess (randomGuess ())
    let rec loop turnCount remaining =
        if Set.count remaining = 1 then
            let answer = Set.maxElement remaining
            printfn "The answer is %A, which I calculated in %d turns." answer (turnCount - 1)
        else
            let guess = randomSetElement remaining
            let (whites, blacks) = checkAnswer guess
            printfn "On turn %d I guessed %A, which gave %d white pins and %d black pins." turnCount guess whites blacks
            /// Remove all possibilities from the solution that wouldn't give the
            /// same numbers of white and black pins and continue.
            loop (turnCount + 1) (Set.filter (fun possible -> (whites, blacks) = checkGuess possible guess) remaining)
    // Play the game!
    loop 1 allPossibles
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make this a comment, but it's too long, so it needs to be an answer instead, even though it's not a *complete* answer to your problem.

One problem with your code, as it is now, is this section:

```
for candidate in candidateSet do
    let scString = candidate.ToString()

    let mutable secretList = []
    for i = 0 to 3 do
        let digit = (int scString.[i])-(int '0')
        secretList <- secretList @ [digit]
    let tempCode = List.map (fun x -> numberToCodeColorPlus (x)) secretList
//Validate works and returns a peg set (b,w)..e.g. (0,0)    
let secretCodePegs = validate guess tempCode
    if secretCodePegs <> guessPegs then
        candidateSet <- Set.remove candidate candidateSet
```

F#, like Python, uses indentation to denote blocks. So that `let secretCodePegs = validate guess tempCode` line is **outside** the `for` loop, not inside the `for` loop the way you clearly intended it to be. And the `if secretCodePegs <> guessPegs then` line that follows it, as far as F# is concerned, is part of a *new* block, and not part of the `for` loop any longer (because the `let secretCodePegs = ...` line ended the `for` loop). All you need to do is indent the `let secretCodePegs = ...` line by one level, and your code will work. In other words, that section *should* have looked like this:

```
for candidate in candidateSet do
    let scString = candidate.ToString()

    let mutable secretList = []
    for i = 0 to 3 do
        let digit = (int scString.[i])-(int '0')
        secretList <- secretList @ [digit]
    let tempCode = List.map (fun x -> numberToCodeColorPlus (x)) secretList
    //Validate works and returns a peg set (b,w)..e.g. (0,0)    
    let secretCodePegs = validate guess tempCode
    if secretCodePegs <> guessPegs then
        candidateSet <- Set.remove candidate candidateSet
```